# SQL - add +1 only for the action with lowest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, exists

I have a table like this:

```
Item_ID   Action_Code         Date_of_action
1           Code'A'            2019-01-01
1           Code'B'            2019-01-15
1           Code'C'            2019-02-05
2           Code'B'            2020-03-05
```

What I need to do is to add +1 to every record (Item) where specific action was done and then SUM all these actions so the output should look like this:

```
Action_Code       Total_number_of_actions
Code'A'            5
Code'B'            8
Code'C'           11
```

The problem is that I need to add +1 only ONCE per record, this OUTER APPLY would add +1 multiple times on one Item if there would be more actions on that Item. I need to add +1 only to the action which was done FIRST on that item. 
I use OUTER APPLY in my code and I am adding the 1 via CASE like this:

```
OUTER APPLY(
SELECT
CASE WHEN 
 EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.Action a1 
INNER JOIN dbo.ActionType at1 
    ON at1.ActionType_id = a1.ActionType_id1
        WHERE at1.Code in ('Code A')
        AND a1.Item_id1 = i.Item_Id

)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Code A'
)MyOuterApply
```

This part of the code will check if the "Code A" exists on the item and if so, it will add +1. The problem is that there could also be action with "Code B" on that item. In that case I want to add +1 to the action "Code A" only if the "Code A" action was done before the "Code B".

How can I say to SQL - When exists action "Code A" and that action was done before "Action B""Action C" on that item, then add +1?
Also I cannot use CTE! I would like to do it in this CASE.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match with Sample Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count how many times each action appears first for a given item, you can do

```
select action_code, count(*) no_actions
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by date_of_action) rn
    from dbo.action a
) a
where rn = 1
group by action_code
```

The subquery ranks records having the same `item_id` by ascending `date_of_action`; the outer query filters on the first record per group, and aggregates by `action_code`.

Comment: Thank you. You sir are the MVP of my day!

Comment: One more question - 

OUTER APPLY(
SELECT
CASE WHEN 
(
select count(*) Pocet_prvnich
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by a.item_id1 order by a.DateOfAction) rn
    from dbo.action a WITH(NOLOCK)
 where a.ActionType_id1 in(20,403,21)
)a
where rn = 1
AND a.Item_Id1 = i.Item_Id
AND a.ActionType_id1 = 20
group by a.ActionType_id1
) NOT IN (0)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Action A'
)MyOuterApply

Honestly its working, but its slow like hell. Do you have any ideas or common method, how to make it faster? OPTION (FORCE ORDER, OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN), didnt help much.